# Violation of access with pointers and scanf

Tags: c, function, pointers, scanf

The following code is supposed to insert the name of a good, whether it's getting stored or sent away (with just a single letter, like i for in or o for out) and in conclusion how much of that item is getting moved.
Then the program should end whenever I write the END phrase.

Problem is, I am finding a violation of access while trying to save the number of items, and cannot seem to find where I am doing something wrong.

```
#define MAX 20
#define END "FINE"

typedef struct type_struct {
    char name[MAX];
    char move[2];
    int quantity;
    struct type_struct* next;
}type;

void insert(type* p) {

    type* aux;

    aux = p;
    while (aux != NULL) 
        aux = aux->next;
    
    aux = malloc(sizeof(type));

    printf("name of good: ");
    scanf("%s", aux->name);
    getchar();
    printf("in or out?: ");
    scanf("%c", aux->move);
    
    printf("quantity: ");
    scanf("%d", aux->quantity);
    printf("\n");

}

int main(void) {

    type* phrase=NULL;
    char fine[5];

    strcpy(fine, END);

    do {
        insert(phrase);
    } while ((strcmp(phrase, fine) == 0));

}
```

It should be very simple, however, I am clueless and hope you might give me a hand

Comment: `scanf("%d", &aux->quantity);`

Comment: `phrase` will always be NULL because insert doesn't modify it or return any value. You can't directly compare `phrase` to `fine` because they are not the same type (and `phrase` is always NULL anyway, causing undefined behavior, possibly access violation).

Comment: You must pass the address of a variable when you use scanf(). put & sign as a prefix of aux->quantity.

Comment: "Violation of access" is a runtime error. It means you missed something in the build phase. I strongly recommend you to build with all warnings enabled, and to follow up on them!